# How to import in code in nodejs when socket is being used?

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I am trying this way:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("client connected: " + client.id);
    io.sockets.socket(client.id).emit("connected", client.id);
    client.on("sendMessage", function (data) {
        //send message code 
    });
});
```

What i want sendMessage code should be in separate file. So how to do ?

What i have tried :

```
//in first.js:
var events = require('events');
var em = new events.EventEmitter();
var msg = require('./message.js');
var emitter = msg.em;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("client connected: " + client.id);
    io.sockets.socket(client.id).emit("connected", client.id);
    emitter.emit('sendMessage');
});


//in message.js

client.on("sendMessage", function (data) {
    //return "Hello";
    //perform db operation
});
```

whether it is correct or wrong ? Can anyone help?
        or is there any new correct way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the handler in some other file and export it.

Main code:

```
const sendMessage = require('./send-message');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("client connected: " + client.id);
    io.sockets.socket(client.id).emit("connected", client.id);
    client.on("sendMessage", sendMessage);
});
```

send-message.js:

```
module.exports = function (data) {
    //send message code 
});
```

Comment: but client i need to pass also. how to pass client in sendMessage ?

Comment: thank you for answer @rsp, I have solved by socket.on("sendMessage", function(data) {
 sendMessage(client, data);
});